# Estimating parameters of multivariate regression using the maximum likelihood method with a uniform distribution of residuals?

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, residuals, uniform-distribution, multivariate-regression

Representation of regression in a matrix form:
$$Y = XA + E,$$

where: $X$ - independent variables, $Y$ - dependent variables (observations), $E$ - errors, which have a uniform distribution, $A$ - regression parameter.

How to evaluate the parameters $A$ of this multivariate regression using the maximum likelihood method with a uniform distribution of errors?

Comment: Is the range of the uniform distribution given or does it need to be estimated?  What do you assume about the independence (or lack thereof) of $E$?

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the answer!
Given:
E = [e1, e2, ..., en] ’, // vector of residuals
Where ei = U [-ui, ui];
The residuals ei have a uniform distribution with a known range [-ui, ui],
All residuals are independent.
I need to estimate the vector of parameters A and its variance.